# How can I create a Promise in TypeScript from a union type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Thanks in advance for the assistance. I'm a TypeScript noob. Here is a snippet of TypeScript code that doesn't work. I'm trying to wrap a union type into a Promise and return it, but I'm not sure how to do it correctly.

```
export interface Foo {
  bar: number;
  baz: number
}

export const promiseFoo(foo: Foo | null): Promise<Foo | null> => ({
  return new Promise<Foo | null>(foo);
});
```

The code above yields the following type error ...

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node-fm/src/index.ts:226
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
index.ts:7:3 - error TS2322: Type '{ return: Promise<Foo>; }' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Foo>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'return' does not exist in type 'Promise<Foo>'.

7   return new Promise<Foo | null>(foo);
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
index.ts:7:34 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Foo' is not assignable to parameter of type '(resolve: (value: Foo | PromiseLike<Foo>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void'.
  Type 'Foo' provides no match for the signature '(resolve: (value: Foo | PromiseLike<Foo>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void): void'.

7   return new Promise<Foo | null>(foo);
                                   ~~~
index.ts:6:24 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

6 export const promiseFoo(foo: Foo | null): Promise<Foo | null> => ({
                         ~
index.ts:7:10 - error TS1005: ':' expected.

7   return new Promise<Foo | null>(foo);
           ~~~
index.ts:7:38 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

7   return new Promise<Foo | null>(foo);
                                       ~

    at createTSError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node-fm/src/index.ts:226:12)
    at getOutput (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node-fm/src/index.ts:335:40)
    at Object.compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node-fm/src/index.ts:368:11)
    at startRepl (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node-fm/src/bin.ts:147:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node-fm/src/bin.ts:66:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
repl process died unexpectedly: exit status 1

```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, that's not valid syntax. If you want to assign a value to a `const` you need an equals sign.

```
export const promiseFoo = ...
```

---

Second, the `=> ({ return new Promise() })` is also not valid syntax.  This is the syntax for returning an object literal from an arrow function. To have a normal function body you need to remove the parens here:

```
=> {
  return new Promise<Foo | null>(foo);
};
```

---

So now you should have this:

```
export const promiseFoo = (foo: Foo | null): Promise<Foo | null> => {
  return new Promise<Foo | null>(foo);
};
```

Now you have valid syntax, but typescript gives you one type error:

> Argument of type
> `'Foo | null'`
> is not assignable to parameter of type
> `'(resolve: (value: Foo | PromiseLike<Foo | null> | null) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void'`.

If you read that carefully, you see that typescript is complaining becuase you are trying to assign `Foo | null` to something that expects a function.

This is because you are not creating a `Promise` correctly. The correct usage of the `Promise` constructor takes a callback function as its argument, which lets you run the code that will resolve the promise. You cannot just pass it the value to resolve.

That might look like this:

```
export const promiseFoo = (foo: Foo | null): Promise<Foo | null> => {
  return new Promise<Foo | null>(resolve => {
    resolve(foo)
  });
};
```

And because typescript is pretty smart, you don't need to explictly declare the type of the promise. It knows the type of `foo`, and it knows the expected return type. This means it's safe to do simply this:

```
export const promiseFoo = (foo: Foo | null): Promise<Foo | null> => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(foo)
  });
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=3&pln=6&pc=1&strict=true#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgMQgjgG8BYAKDjgCNMoAuOJAVwFsa0BuS6ugLyasOaSgF9KlUJFhxsEJAGd4YKBDYJFwQsQC8cABToiTHXAA+zFgBtrASiYAFNRq0AeM5da2AfHF1+5FRwUMAwLFBIzMAA7nDO6prABqGKENYAbngBpLzUIcBpmcnGEHZ5YnY8FGJcQA)

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems with your code:

1. You have some syntax errors. Fix it like this:

   ```
   export interface Foo {
     bar: number;
     baz: number
   }

   export const promiseFoo = (foo: Foo | null): Promise<Foo | null> => {
     return new Promise<Foo | null>(foo);
   };
   ```
2. A promise takes a function, but you pass `Foo | null` to it. What you can do is to just resolve the promise with the foo value:

   ```
   export interface Foo {
     bar: number;
     baz: number
   }

   export const promiseFoo = (foo: Foo | null): Promise<Foo | null> => {
     return new Promise<Foo | null>(resolve => resolve(foo));
   };
   ```

   There is a shorthand called `Promise.resolve()`:

   ```
   export interface Foo {
     bar: number;
     baz: number
   }

   export const promiseFoo = (foo: Foo | null): Promise<Foo | null> => {
     return Promise.resolve(foo);
   };
   ```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your syntax for creating an arrow function is written in the wrong way.

```
//Arrow function
(a: number, b: number): number => a + b;
// We can use arrow function as a callback function.
const callBack = (a: number, b: number): number => a + b;
```

Correct code

```
export interface Foo {
  bar: number;
  baz: number
}

type FooWithNull = Foo | null;

// using arrow function
export const promiseFoo = (foo: FooWithNull): Promise<FooWithNull> => {
 return new Promise<FooWithNull>(resolve => resolve(foo)); 
}

// using pure function
export function anotherPromiseFoo(foo: Promise<FooWithNull>): Promise<Foo | null>{
  return new Promise<FooWithnull>(resolve => resolve(foo));
}
```